# Export interpolation results from R as GeoTIFF for import to OpenLayers

Tags: r, openlayers, geospatial, geotiff

As a part of the research project on ecology, our team need to interpolate results of analysis of snow probes for pollutants. For that task we utilize Inverse distance weighting from R software.

For now, we use the following code for data reading and preparations:

```
library(sf)
library(stars)
library(tmap)
library(raster)
library(plotly)
library(mapview)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggrepel)
library(dismo) 
library(akima) 
library(gstat) 
library(deldir)

options(scipen=999)

pts = read_table2("D:/www/baikal_so4.dat") %>% st_as_sf(coords = c('x', 'y'), crs = 4326, remove = FALSE)
pts = st_transform(pts, 3857)

coords = st_coordinates(pts)
box = st_bbox(pts)
envelope = box[c(1,3,2,4)]

px_grid = st_as_stars(box, dx = 500, dy = 500)

# Extracting points coordinates:
coords_grid = st_coordinates(px_grid)

#Initing color mapping
stat_colors = colorRampPalette(c('#7EBEDE', '#93C4D9','#A1C9D4','#B2D2CE', '#B9D4C6','#C3D9BB','#D2E3B9','#DDE8B0','#EEF2B1','#F9FBA5','#FDF798','#FDE791','#FBD992','#F9CB8A','#F8BF86','#F5B180','#F5A57C','#F39779','#F18272','#EF7474'))

stat_levels = seq(0, 3, by=0.2)
stat_ncolors = length(stat_levels)-1
           
stat_legend = scale_fill_manual(name = 'mg/l', values = stat_colors(stat_ncolors), guide = guide_legend(label.vjust = -0.3, reverse = TRUE, title.position = "bottom"), labels = stat_levels, na.value = 'white', drop = FALSE)

stat_mapping = aes(fill = cut(values, breaks = stat_levels))

#Delaune triangulation
edges = pts %>% 
  st_union() %>% 
  st_triangulate()
```

Code for interpolation

```
px_grid = px_grid %>% 
  mutate(z_idw2 = gstat::idw(values ~ 1, locations = pts, newdata = px_grid, idp = 2.0) %>% pull(var1.pred) %>% as('vector'),
         z_idw3 = gstat::idw(values ~ 1, locations = pts, newdata = px_grid, idp = 3.0) %>% pull(var1.pred) %>% as('vector'),
         z_idw4 = gstat::idw(values ~ 1, locations = pts, newdata = px_grid, idp = 4.0) %>% pull(var1.pred) %>% as('vector'),
         z_idw5 = gstat::idw(values ~ 1, locations = pts, newdata = px_grid, idp = 5.0) %>% pull(var1.pred) %>% as('vector'))
         
cont_idw2 = st_contour(px_grid['z_idw2'], 
                       breaks = stat_levels, 
                       contour_lines = TRUE)

cont_idw3 = st_contour(px_grid['z_idw3'], 
                       breaks = stat_levels, 
                       contour_lines = TRUE)

cont_idw4 = st_contour(px_grid['z_idw4'], 
                       breaks = stat_levels, 
                       contour_lines = TRUE)

cont_idw5 = st_contour(px_grid['z_idw5'], 
                       breaks = stat_levels, 
                       contour_lines = TRUE)

ggplot() +
  geom_stars(data = cut(px_grid['z_idw5'], breaks = stat_levels)) +
  stat_legend +
  coord_sf(crs = st_crs(pts)) +
  geom_sf(data = cont_idw5, color = 'black', size = 0.2) +
  geom_sf(data = pts, color = 'red', size = 0.5) +
  geom_sf(data = edges, color = 'red', size = 0.1, fill = NA)
```

Which give us this result [image]

In this question I don't consider the correctness of the result. The problem is that we need  to export this result to our Web application that uses OpenLayers library. When I try to export for example, `px_grid['z_idw5']` to GeoTiff using `write_stars` method, I get the following result which looks, well, close to the first one, but without colors.
[image]

So, my question is: how can I export the results of the interpolation to GeoTIFF with predefined colors?

Comment: You need to convert your one-layer raster into a three-layer raster with red, green, and blue bands created by lookup from the single value into your colour scale, then you can save as a three-band RGB TIFF. To get the exact colours you need to know what `geom_stars` is using as a palette and colour breakpoints.

Comment: @Spacedman if I get you right then you can see palette and breakpoints in the first part of the code, `stat_colors` and `stat_levels `. But how can I convert it to three layer raster?

Comment: Write a function that takes a data value and the colour mapping and returns the red, green, and blue components for that value. Then evaluate that over your raster to get a set of red, green, and blue values you can put into 3 layers of a new stars raster object. Sorry this is just an outline at present but hopefully that's the direction you can go.